# multipage form with validation via sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Good day, I have an app which creates a user via a multipage form (no interactions with db  except the last step are allowed!)

So on the first page user enters his email
second his address
third company info (or whatsoever)
fourth page - it's all the info is displayed & user is saved into db.

my solution was as follows:
step one: new action of users_controller. it's view

```
- if notice
  p[class='notice'] = notice
p Enter your personal data
= form_tag step2_path do 
  p
    = label_tag 'Email'
    = text_field_tag 'user[email]'
  p  
    = submit_tag 'Continue'
```

users#create

```
def create
    session[:user] = {}
    redirect_to step2_path
  end
```

step2,3,4 are the same action. 
routes.rb

```
  match 'step2' => 'user_signup#steps'
  match 'step3' => 'user_signup#steps'
  match 'step4' => 'user_signup#steps'

class UserSignupController < ApplicationController

  def steps
    @check = true
    path = request.env['PATH_INFO'][1..-1]
    update
    if path == 'step4' 
      @user = User.create(session[:user])
    end
    render "user_signup/#{path}"
  end
def update
    session[:user] = if session[:user].present?
      session[:user].merge(params[:user]) { |key, old, new| new } 
    else
      params[:user]
    end
  end
```

and on each step (2,3,4) params[:user][xxx] is created...
will there be any hints?

**UPDATE**
I've decided to apply http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
And after that to use Presenter pattern http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-presenter-pattern.html

Comment: I'm not sure what question you're trying to ask here, can you elaborate?

Comment: I've edited my post, thanks for asking! it helped me to straighten my mind